# How to make a POST request in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

Here is my code, my code is working but my problem is when i try to pass variables instead of name on `NSString *postString = @"username=example&firstlastname=example";` where it says example i want to = a TextField value, so how can I do this? I have tried post string appending string but it did not work. Please help

```
NSURL *aUrl= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxx/iqueueinsertinjoinq.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = @"username=example&firstlastname=example";

[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self ];}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you would want is this:
Change:

```
NSString *postString = @"username=example&firstlastname=example";
```

To:

```
NSString *username = @"foo";
NSString spokenname = @"bar";
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&firstlastname=%@", username, spokenname];
```

NSString's stringWithFormat: allows for variable substitution in the format string. In my example, "username" would be the NSString variable containing the user name, and "spokenname" is the firstnamelastname string.